# Running daphne behind nginx reverse proxy with protocol upgrade always routes to http instead of websocket

Tags: python, django, nginx, websocket, django-channels

I am trying to deploy django channels powered notification application behind Nginx reverse proxy server to only serve the websocket communications, while having Nginx + uWSGI setup to serve the django application.

The application works in my local machine seamlessly when run with either `python manage.py runserver --noasgi` + `daphne -p 8000 myproject.asgi:application` or `python manage.py runserver` with `daphne` handling all the requests internally.

**Problem:**

All the websocket requests are routed to `http` protocol type instead of `websocket` protocol type and it returns `WebSocket connection to 'ws://ip_address/ws/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

**Packages Installed:**

```
Django==2.0.3
channels==2.0.2
channels-redis==2.1.1
daphne==2.1.0
asgiref==2.3.0
Twisted==17.9.0
aioredis==1.0.0
autobahn==18.4.1
```

**Environment:**

```
Ubuntu - 16.04
Nginx - 1.12.0
```

**Nginx Configuration for upgrading the request:**

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to websocket requests
upstream websocket {
    server unix:/path/to/my/app/daphne.sock;
}

# configuration of the server
server {

        # the port your site will be served on
        listen      80;

        # the domain name it will serve for
        server_name ip_address;
        charset     utf-8;

       # Sending all non-media requests for websockets to the Daphne server.
        location /ws/ {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }

}
```

**routing.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from myapp import consumers

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            url(r'^ws/$', consumers.MyConsumer),
        ])
    ),
})
```

**Daphne Logs:**

```
None - - [TimeStamp] "GET /ws/" 404 3
None - - [TimeStamp] "GET /ws/" 404 3
None - - [TimeStamp] "GET /ws/" 404 3
```

Kindly let me know if anything in addition is required to help.

P.S: I have deployed the same application in two servers(both having the same configuration and environment as above) and the result was same.

Comment: Please, add this to the channels GitHub repository in the docs, seems a fine deployment solution in my opinion. Can you please provide more information about the daphne socket and the ssl redirect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I found that the culprit was my company's firewall, which was stripping the upgrade headers when application was accessed over `http`. So after upgrading `http` to `https`, it started working as expected.